# Function to write lines in CSV file? Or parse list?

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script with no functions. At the moment, it takes in an input `file1.txt` and outputs a string with results from the calculation, i.e.

```
file1.txt 12 16.0 True
```

I would like to run through dozens of text files and write these strings into a CSV file, row by row.

Does one append each output into a list, and then parse the list? This feels like you should write a function to take each input and output the calculations directly into a CSV file.

How do I take the inputs from each time I run the script, e.g. filename, data result, data result 2, Boolean result, and write this to the file using 
`csv.writer.writerow()`?

```
import csv
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'wt')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow( ('Filename', 'data', 'data', 'Boolean' )
    writer.writerow( % (f, ..., ..., str(...) )
finally:
    f.close()

print open(sys.argv[1], 'rt').read()
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. It seems you more or less know how to proceed? I suggest you write a first version of your code, if you encounter any specific problem, ask a new question, if not, you can go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to have architecture and style advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obtain the list of your arguments from sys.argv

```
arg_list = sys.argv[1:]
```

and then create a loop after create the writer

```
  f = open(sys.argv[1], 'wt') arg_list = sys.argv[1:] 
  try:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow( ('Filename', 'data', 'data', 'Boolean' )
        for arg in arg_list:
          writer.writerow( % (f, ..., ..., str(...) ) # your row
  finally:
        f.close()

  print open(sys.argv[1], 'rt').read()
```

meanwhile, if you need a single row to write in csv, the code'll be

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'wt')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow( ('Filename', 'data', 'data', 'Boolean' )
    writer.writerow(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
finally:
    f.close()

print open(sys.argv[1], 'rt').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment. Just wanted to clarify if you are assuming to read from a folder. If you are, why don't you run a loop and store your results into a dataframe/list and then write that into the csv. Let me know if this approach works with you and I can write the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean to call the already existing python script from another script, catch its results and push them into your CSV.

Actually, you should think about rewriting your first Python script and wrap its functionality into a function which takes a filename as an argument and returns the respective results:

```
def do_stuff(thefile):
    # Perform activity here
    return (a, b, c)
```

Then iterate your text files (or use `map`) and collect the results.

If you **really** want to stick to calling one script from another (think twice!), which is absolutely not what you should do, you can read further on `subprocess.call()` or `os.system()`. I will not provide an example here to not support this approach.

Comment: No, I was hoping to rewrite a second Python script.